# Is there a difference between 60 watts of heat delivered by AC or DC power?

Tags: resistors, heat

I am considering substituting a 60W AC heating element with one of the same wattage that runs on DC power. Would there be any noticeable difference between the heat given by the two if they are the same wattage rating?

Comment: AC or DC, RMS value of current is all that matters to compute the power ...

Comment: The devil is in the detail; link the data sheets.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a difference between 60 watts of heat delivered by AC or DC power?

There is so much ***no difference*** between AC and DC heating, that comparing the two is how the standards laboratories all over the world achieve traceability for their AC standards, from their primary DC standards.

Comment: Apart from the heat output you may see some differences, perhaps most notably than a DC heater won’t hum at AC line frequency, but may produce a magnetic field.  For most applications these are irrelevant, but could matter if you’re recording music in a neodymium refinery.

Answer (score 3):

Heating elements are typically simple resistive loads. This means the power they dissipate is directly proportional to the voltage applied squared. Whether it’s AC or DC does not make a difference.

The power rating of your AC heating element is likely based on the assumption that you’re running it at 120 VRMS (in the US). This means the total resistance of the element is probably ~240 ohm. If you hook that puppy up to a 120 VDC source, it will give off just as much heat as it did hooked up to the AC source. If you hook it up to a AAA battery though you will be disappointed (~10 mW instead of 60 W).

Comment: If it were a 60W incandescent light bulb, it would light up for DC.

Comment: @Ryan: "the power they dissipate is directly proportional to the voltage applied" is wrong. If the element is a simple (Ohmic) resistive load, then the power is directly proportional to the **voltage squared**: P = V * I = V * V / R. Doubeling the voltage would quadruple the power.

Comment: @Curd good point, I’ll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

RMS 60W of AC power is equivalent to 60W DC power. It should be the same.

---

Edited.
Thanks to @Andyaka & @OskaSkog, for a good lesson.
average AC power = (rms I)^2 x R = (rms V)^2 / R = DC power

Thus, the correct statement would be: Average 60W of AC power is equivalent to 60W DC power.

Comment: There is no such tangible thing as *RMS 60W*.

Comment: Yap, it's embarrassing. , I admit I was not certain about my wording. One up to your comment @Andyaka. Would you, please, be able to correct it?

Comment: You can correct it can't you?

Comment: RMS voltage or current -> **average** power

Answer (score 0):

Usually no. Unless your DC source voltage happens to be the same as your AC voltage - I doubt it is - you can't do it.

Comment: The OP may indeed be running the DC heating element at a different voltage (the voltage specified for its rated power), otherwise why change it?